# Supported Audio Formats of Qt4 Phonon?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, phonon

I am making a music player in PyQt4, and I am using Phonon to play the music itself. This application is aimed primarily at Windows, but I plan on also supporting Mac and Linux versions. What I want to know is which audio formats are supported by Phonon so that I can ensure that the user only enters those files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [call *availableMimeTypes()* to check what formats the backend supports](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/phonon-overview.html#querying-backends-for-support).